# Why are class names not obfuscated by Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard

All class name are kept, NOT replaced by A,B,C...

proguard rules as following gist link
https://gist.github.com/YongboWu/7ba37e82cd3f56a235c0

In Android Studio, Proguard is enabled:

```
        release {
           minifyEnabled true
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

example class that I want to proguard

```
public class PortfolioListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
  private float a;
  private float b;
  private float c;
  private float d;
  ......
}
```

Google the reason for hours, can not find the reason.

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Could you paste an example of which classes you'd like to obfuscate but are being kept?

Comment: Have you checked you selected the release build variant?

Comment: select release build variant ? how in android studio ?

Comment: add an example class already

Comment: Paste your proguard-rules.pro file, to find help from SO members